# Two controllers at once?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hi I have no clue how to use two different controllers at the same time and pass data to one view? I mean I have my BlogController and StatisticsController. Statistics among other things is showing how many people is online and I wanted to this data would be on main page of my blog.
I can see two ways that it could work: 
-create some ContainerController and make objects of BlogController and StatisticsController and there manipulating both methods
-create object of StatisticsController in BlogController
but I'm not sure about theese solutions. Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely unclear. From what I understand you have a controller action returning a view that needs to incorporate some information on a part of the screen. This information is accessible through another controller action returning a partial view. If this is the case then the [Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper might be exactly what you are looking for.

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class StatisticsController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

And in the Index view of the blog controller include the statistics:

```
<%= Html.RenderAction("Index", "Statistics") %>
```

The same could be achieved including directly a partial view without the need of passing through a controller:

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial("~/views/statistics/index.ascx") %>
```

but the advantage of the RenderAction is that if the statistics requires some specific repository it would be better to pass through a controller.